# How do I use RequiredValidator to validate a RadioButtonList in Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

We have a RadioButtonList control inside a Repeater control with two options, Yes or No.

We would like to force our users to choose a Yes or No before proceeding.

In other words, if a user clicks to submit or in our case, click the Next button to go to the next without selecting either Yes or No, an error needs to be raised letting the user know that s/he must select a Yes or No to continue.

The following code uses RequiredValidator control to handle this but it does not do anything.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
Purchased:<asp:radiobuttonlist ID="rblType" runat="server" ValidationGroup ="stype" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right" style="display:inline;">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="No" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                ControlToValidate="rblType"
                ErrorMessage="required"
                ValidationGroup ="stype" 
                runat="server"/>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I often use a dropdown for a case like this with three options where the first option is empty (nothing selected). Yes and no radio button is like a switch: one or the other must be selected. Actually iPhones and android phones have designed them to be a switch: it is not possible for the user or the system to define another state.

Comment: your code should work, maybe the problem is related to the repeater, have you tried the same code outside of the repeater ?

Comment: @Etienne, hi.

The code works outside of repeater. You brought up an excellent point.

I have traditionally had problems with dropdownlist, checkboxlist and radiobuttonlist in repeater. Not sure why it is that hard with repeater.

I tried jquery which works outside of repeater but not within repeater. So, that's why I emphasized repeater in my question because there must be some trick to making it work within repeater.